# Php get all filenames eachother with lines of every file

Tags: php, file, directory, lines

I need to get 1 or two lines from every file I get from dir. I have these two codes, but I can't find figure out how to combine each other.

```
$path = "mydir/";
$files = scandir($path);
$files = array_diff($files, array('.', '..'));

foreach ($files as $value) {

    echo "<a href='".$value."' target='_black' >".$value."</a><br/>";

}
```

This returns every file from my directory.

```
$lines  = @file("mydir/myfile.txt");
$i=1;
foreach($lines  as $line ){

$var["line" . $i] = $line;
$i++;
}
extract($var);

echo $line2;
```

And this returns second line from my file.

I've tried this:

```
$path = "mydir/";
$files = scandir($path);
$files = array_diff($files, array('.', '..'));

$lines  = @file("mydir/".$files);
    $i=1;

foreach (array_combine($files, $lines) as $value => $line) {

$var["line" . $i] = $line;
    $i++;
    extract($var);

    echo "<a href='".$value."' target='_black' >".$value.$line2."</a><br/>";

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

each line is 1024 bytes!
so with bread you can read 2 lines with is 2048 bytes...

fread($fileopen,2048);

hope it helps <3

Comment: @Simon no problem,just find the line(but strpos or same functions) and then try to read that line. if you want the full code just explain what that line is and where is it i'll show you.